# Consistency of Tense

Tags: grammaticality, grammar

> You have found a job. You get called in by the company for a job interview and it went great.

Is there something wrong with this sentence? Is there an inappropriate shift in tense? If yes, how should it be written?

Comment: Yes, you should say "you got a job. You got called and...it went well" OR use all the tenses in the present.

Comment: @BenyaminHamidekhoo- actually, saying "you got a job" means that you have been hired.  I think OP is saying that you've found a job opening [and have applied].

Comment: "Should" by what obligation? This is a bit like saying: "My neighbour's house has a blue door. My house has a red door. Is that an inappropriate shift in door colour?"

Comment: @Neil. Only in the context if you were speaking only about red doors... Think of it this way, the red door is the present and the blue door would be the past. Context is all so important!

Answer (score 3):

This is really a matter of stylistic preference/effect rather than grammaticality as such.

Essentially, your sentence is evoking three events or 'moments':

> Moment A: Finding a job.
>
> Moment B: Getting called for interview.
>
> Moment C: The interview.

As your sentence stands, it recounts moments (A) and (B) as though they are 'unfolding in front of your eyes', and then-- through the use of the past tense-- recounts moment (C) as though 'it has already happened and the "moment" is an evaluation of that event'.

Now, if you recount Moment (C) using the present tense, you also recount it more as though it is 'unfolding' than as a result.

So is either tense "wrong"? Well... it depends on the particular emphasis you want to place as you are recounting the event. There's no God-given obligation to place one emphasis or the other-- it's a question of stylistic/pragmatic preference.

Comment: @Neil... not true, as there is a reason for proper tense. You prove this yourself by placing an imposed tense right on your reply... '_on the particular emphasis you want to place as you are **recounting** the event_.'. Recounting is past tense. You are making the assumption then that the OP is speaking in the past tense already.

Comment: ***NO***, absolutely not! Just because you are recounting something that took place physically in the past does ***NOT*** mean any a priori obligation whatsoever to use any particular tense. And specifically, there is no obligation whatsoever for a past event to be evoked using a "past" tense. Remember terms like "past" and "present" tense are just arbitrary made-up labels: we could equally call them "tense A", "tense B" etc...

Comment: ...So what your argument boils down to is saying that it is "proper" to use Tense A to evoke an event that took place in the past and "improper" to use Tense B. Well... why?

Comment: No, what I am saying is you need to stay in the same tense in the same sentence. Either tense can be used, but you have to decide on one or another. Mixing tense can only confuse a reader as to the timeline of the event being described. For example, using the same sentence again with mixed tense... You will find a job. You got called in by the company for a job interview and it is great. See what I mean? You must be consistent in the tense throughout, or it loses any reference to time at all!

Comment: Also, you have changed the tense in A from the original sentence. The orignal tense for A was past (because of 'found') and you changed the tense by making it 'finding' a job in your A. So, to a reader... which is it, did you find a job or are you still looking for a job? In your B, you have changed the tense again to 'getting' which contradicts 'interview went great'... are you waiting to get called for an interview that you also have already been too? You see why tense is NOT just 'arbitrary made-up labels'... they establish a timeline for the events described.

Comment: @Epiphany I'm honestly not sure I see what the big confusion is, but in any case, that's something the writer would need to weigh up, just as they would with any stylistic choice such as putting a comma in a particular place, using a particular choice of vocabulary or particular sentence length etc. But the fact remains that in English per se, there is no such tense constraint as the one you mention.

Comment: @Epiphany Now, as you say, tenses can indeed establish a timeline. And my point is that in this case, using present vs past tense establishes two different variants of the timeline. (P.S. Barring a big philosophical debate, -ing forms are essentially tenseless -- at least in this context -- and I was careful to use -ing forms in my list specifically for that reason.)

Answer (score 1):

It should be modified as in the following to imply past tense.

1.) '**You found a job**'  instead of  'You have found a job', as the have is not necessary, because 'found' already implies the past tense. 'Have' usually implies the present (with 'had' being the past tense), and saying 'I had found a job' sounds funny, yet is tense correct.

2.) '**You got called in by the company**'  instead of  'You get called in by the company', as 'get' implies the present and got implies the past. This change ties the tense into the 'job interview and it **went** great' end of the sentence, implying that the interview had already happened with the 'went' (past tense).